# function not being called on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I've taken all your comments on board and changed the code to the below. However now everything ends up in a string in the address bar and the page refreshes. My code is now:

Part of form:

```
<form class="inline" name="Form1">
<input class="inline" name="employeeid" id="employeeid" type="hidden" size="30" autofocus value="<?php echo $employee[$k]["employeeid"]; ?>" />
.... more fields here.....
<p class="inline">
        <label class="inline" for="pensionindividual">Individual Pension:</label>
        <input class="inline" id="pensionindividual" type="text" name="pensionindividual" size="30" value="<?php echo $employee[$k]["pensionindividual"]; ?>" />
    </p>
    <p class="inline">
        <label class="inline" for="pensioncompany">Company Pension:</label>
        <input class="inline" type="text" id="pensioncompany" name="pensioncompany" size="30" value="<?php echo $employee[$k]["pensioncompany"]; ?>" />
    </p>
    <input id="submit" type="submit" onclick="NewSearchFunction(e)" value="Update Details">
       </td></tr></table></td></tr></table>
</form>
<script src="editemployeedetailsajax.js"></script>
```

editemployeedetailsajaxjs:

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function
NewSearchFunction(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

var employeeid=document.getElementById("employeeid").value;
var firstname=document.getElementById("firstname").value;
var surname=document.getElementById("lastname").value;
var addr1=document.getElementById("addr1").value;
var addr2=document.getElementById("addr2").value;
var town=document.getElementById("town").value;
var county=document.getElementById("county").value;
var postcode=document.getElementById("postcode").value;
var tel1=document.getElementById("tel1").value;
var work=document.getElementById("work").value;
var mobile=document.getElementById("mobile").value;
var sex=document.getElementById("sex").value;
var DOB=document.getElementById("DOB").value;
var ninumber=document.getElementById("ninumber").value;
var payrollnumber=document.getElementById("payrollnumber").value;
var sortcode=document.getElementById("sortcode").value;
var accountnumber=document.getElementById("accountnumber").value;
var annualleaveentitlement=document.getElementById("annualleaveentitlement").value;
var vehicleid=document.getElementById("vehicleid").value;
var fuelcardid=document.getElementById("fuelcardid").value;
var mobileid=document.getElementById("mobileid").value;
var pensionindividual=document.getElementById("pensionindividual").value;
var pensioncompany=document.getElementById("pensioncompany").value;

// Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.

var dataString = '&employeeid=' + employeeid + '&firstname=' + firstname + '&surname=' + lastname + '&addr1=' + addr1 + '&addr2=' + addr2 + '&town=' + town + '&county=' + county + '&postcode=' + postcode + '&tel1=' + tel1 + '&work=' + work + '&mobile=' + mobile + '&sex=' + sex + '&DOB=' + DOB + '&ninumber=' + ninumber + '&payrollnumber=' + payrollnumber + '&sortcode=' + sortcode + '&accountnumber=' + accountnumber + '&annualleaveentitlement=' + annualleaveentitlement + '&vehicleid=' + vehicleid + '&fuelcardid=' + fuelcardid + '&mobileid=' + mobileid + '&pensionindividual=' + pensionindividual + '&pensioncompany=' + pensioncompany;

// AJAX code to submit form.
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "submit.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html) {
alert(html)});
);
```

> Hi When I submit my form the function that is attached to the submit
>   button does not get called. The form is within a div which is
>   retrieved by ajax based upon user's selection in another div. The
>   javascript is referenced in the header of the first page - I'm not
>   sure if this is the problem.
>
> part of form:
>
> ```
> <div id="mainform">
> <div class="innerdiv">
> <form class="inline" name="Form1">
>     <p class="inline">
>         <label class="inline" for="pensioncompany">Company Pension:</label>
>         <input class="inline" type="text" name="pensioncompany" size="30" value="<?php echo $employee[$k]["pensioncompany"]; ?>" />
>     </p>
>     <input id="submit" type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Update Details">
>        </td></tr></table></td></tr></table>
> </form>
> ```
>
> editemployeeajax.js (all the fields below are part of the form but to
>   simplify the question I only left one in the form above)
>
> ```
> // JavaScript Document
> function myFunction() {
>
> var employeeid=document.getElementById("employeeid").value;
> var firstname=document.getElementById("firstname").value;
> var surname=document.getElementById("lastname").value;
> var addr1=document.getElementById("addr1").value;
> var addr2=document.getElementById("addr2").value;
> var town=document.getElementById("town").value;
> var county=document.getElementById("county").value;
> var postcode=document.getElementById("postcode").value;
> var tel1=document.getElementById("tel1").value;
> var work=document.getElementById("work").value;
> var mobile=document.getElementById("mobile").value;
> var sex=document.getElementById("sex").value;
> var DOB=document.getElementById("DOB").value;
> var ninumber=document.getElementById("ninumber").value;
> var payrollnumber=document.getElementById("payrollnumber").value;
> var sortcode=document.getElementById("sortcode").value;
> var accountnumber=document.getElementById("accountnumber").value;
> var annualleaveentitlement=document.getElementById("annualleaveentitlement").value;
> var vehicleid=document.getElementById("vehicleid").value;
> var fuelcardid=document.getElementById("fuelcardid").value;
> var mobileid=document.getElementById("mobileid").value;
> var pensionindividual=document.getElementById("pensionindividual").value;
> var pensioncompany=document.getElementById("pensioncompany").value;
>
> // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
>
> var dataString = '&employeeid=' + employeeid + '&firstname=' + firstname + '&surname=' + lastname + '&addr1=' + addr1 + '&addr2=' +
> ```
>
> addr2 + '&town=' + town + '&county=' + county + '&postcode=' +
>   postcode + '&tel1=' + tel1 + '&work=' + work + '&mobile=' + mobile +
>   '&sex=' + sex + '&DOB=' + DOB + '&ninumber=' + ninumber +
>   '&payrollnumber=' + payrollnumber + '&sortcode=' + sortcode +
>   '&accountnumber=' + accountnumber + '&annualleaveentitlement=' +
>   annualleaveentitlement + '&vehicleid=' + vehicleid + '&fuelcardid=' +
>   fuelcardid + '&mobileid=' + mobileid + '&pensionindividual=' +
>   pensionindividual + '&pensioncompany=' + pensioncompany;
>
> ```
> // AJAX code to submit form.
> &.ajax({
> type: "POST",
> url: "submit.php",
> data: dataString,
> cache: false,
> success: function(html) {
> alert(html);
> }
> });
> }
> return false;
> }
> ```

Comment: You are returning false at the end. I think the problem is there only. Delete that line and see what happens….....

Comment: Hi. I've deleted that line but still no luck.

Comment: Surely `&.ajax()` is supposed to be `$.ajax()`, right?

Comment: Having done some more reading Im wondering if it's because the handler is attached before the form has been appended to the DOM due to it being in a div that is filled only on user input but im not sur ehow to fix this.

Comment: Also you can generate `dataString` with the single statement `dataString = $("form[name=Form1]").serialize();`

Comment: fixed the $.ajax, I originally was using serialize but when that wasnt working I thought I'd try writing everything out in the hope it would work :-(

Comment: Maybe the DOM hasn't loaded before. Try using '$(document).ready(…)'.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the form submission happens before the onclick event gets processed. Change your HTML block to be `onclick="myFunction(e);"`

Then, change your function to start with the following:

```
function myFunction(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // ... The rest of your code.
}
```

This will stop the form from being submitted and allow your code to execute. You will also not need to return false at the end to stop it from submitting.

The `e` is the onclick event object.

Comment: The submit button `<input>` element has `type="button"`, not `type="submit"`, so it will not submit the form. Easy to mistake since it has `id="submit"`.

Comment: Yeah, I missed that too as OP says "when I submit the form", and this is one of those things that I forget about all the time when I come back to client side coding after a few months away.

Comment: 've taken all your comments on board and changed the code to the below. However now everything ends up in a string in the address bar and the page refreshes

Comment: In the console I get "Reference Error: NewSearchFunction is not defined."

Comment: You don't have a JS variable or function named `NewSearchFunction` in your example code. Also, you can just pass your data in as a JavaScript object instead of turning it into a string.